# Add second CD-Drive to Virtual PC

Tags: windows-xp-mode, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have Windows 7 and I'm running Virtual PC to run XP Mode.  I want to know if there is any way to add a second CD/DVD Drive to the PC.  Right now I only have 1.

Thank you,

Comment: Install a virtual disk emulator program there are several.

Comment: I wanted to install Win95 on the VM.  I was trying to use one CD as boot disk and another as Install disk.